# Plot nth order series as a function of x using R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the nth order of a series with R by making a function of x that asks for input 'order'.

Something like this, but this doesn't work for an arbitrary x, it returns the error: object 'x' not found.

```
fun1 <- function(order,x) {
    output = 0
    for (i in 0:order){
        output = output + ((-1)**order)*((x**(2)/factorial(2*order))
    }
}

plot1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = fun1(0, x), geom = "line")
```

Which would in theory plot the leading order of the sum (-1^order)((x^2)/(2*order)!)

Previously I was writing out each element of the series by hand, but this is tedious when dealing with higher orders.

Edit: an example of what worked previously is this:

```
order4 <- function(x) {
    (1-((x**2)/2)+((x**2)/24)-((x**2)/720))
    }


plot1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = order4, geom = "line")
```

Comment: a couple problems - `stat_function` states the function must be vectorized and is applied to a grid of x values.  Your function is being applied to order + x and is only vectorized on x. There is the `args` argument to pass additional params

Comment: you may be interested in `Reduce` as well, as a generic replacement for functions like yours

Comment: For something like this we just need vectorization and matrix multiplication, not Reduce. First calculate coefficients: `coefs = (-1)^(0:order) / factorial(2 * (0:order))`, then the powers of x, `x_grid = outer(x, 0:order, "^")`, then the result is `x_grid %*% coefs`. (`Reduce` would work too, of course, but a bit less efficient)

Comment: that's definetly better!  `Reduce` can be a useful convience function when you can't vectorize though, and you need to fold.  It can perform much better in other languages as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's modify  your function to make it more general and vectorized:

```
my_series = function(x, order) {
  coefs = (-1)^(0:order) / factorial(2 * (0:order))
  x_grid = outer(x, 0:order, "^")
  x_grid %*% coefs
}

fun(1:5, order = 3) # looks good
#            [,1]
# [1,]  0.5402778
# [2,]  0.1555556
# [3,] -0.1625000
# [4,] -0.4222222
# [5,] -0.6319444
```

I also put the `x` argument first, which seems nice. Now we can use the `args` argument of `stat_function` to pass the `order` in, as mentioned in comments. And we give the data frame the full range of x values we want to plot.

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0:20), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = my_series, geom = "line", args = list(order = 3))
```

[image]

This still works very quickly for higher order:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = -2:280), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = my_series, geom = "line", args = list(order = 20))
```

[image]